lower bound of $\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$
Denote by $\mu$ the Mobius function.  Poussin showed that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = O(1/\log x),
$$
and there are further improvements since.  I wonder what is known about   lower bound of this sum, conditional and otherwise?  What about $\Omega$-results (also for lower bound)?  Thanks!

Yep, these are good questions! Note that $O(1/\log x)$ is both an upper bound and a lower bound for the sum (by definition, $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means that $|f(x)| \le Cg(x)$ for some constant $C$).
Let $M_r(x) = \sum_{n\le x} \mu(n)/n$. Adapting the classical proof of the prime number theorem gives the bound
$$
M_r(x) = O\bigl( e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}} \bigr)
$$
for some constant $c>0$. One can do a bit better with the power of $\log x$ in the exponent, but we can't yet improve this bound to $M_r(x) = O(x^{-\delta})$ for any $\delta$—that would imply a zero-free strip $\sigma>1-\delta$ for the Riemann zeta function.
We expect the truth to be $M_r(x) = O_\varepsilon(x^{-1/2+\varepsilon})$ for every $\varepsilon>0$—that is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis.
As for oscillation results, we can certainly get $M_r(x) = \Omega_\pm(x^{-1/2-\varepsilon})$ for every $\varepsilon>0$.
Conjecturing (much less proving) more precise versions of these (where the $x^\varepsilon$ is replaced by particular powers of $\log x$ or $\log\log x$) is a more difficult proposition. There's a lot more work pertaining to the original Mertens sum $M(x) = \sum_{n\le x} \mu(n)$ and the (now disproved) Mertens conjecture; you could look into that subject to get a flavor of what to expect for $M_r(x)$ (roughly speaking, divide all the bounds for $M(x)$ by $x$).

Many thanks @gregmartin!   Could you give references for the GRH bound $O(x^{-1/2+\epsilon})$ and for the (unconditional) $\Omega$-bound?  And just out of curiosity:  What does the subscript in $M_r$ stand for?

${}_r$ is for “reciprocal”, indicating the $\frac1n$ weight. Check out this annotated bibliography, where you can hopefully find references for these assertions. Admittedly I'm going by analogy with what we know about $M(x)$ and how the $\frac1n$ weights work in other contexts.
